# Nagios NRPE on windows - Run 32 bit tool with 64 bit NSClient++

Tags: nagios

I'm using Nagios core for monitoring a windows server. At the monitored client NSClient++ x64 is installed.

I need to run an NRPE check at the windows client. The check is a vbs. The script must be run with 32 bit.
I've tried some external commands. But it's not working.

If I run the following command, the script is started (but running with 64 bit):

```
check_version=cscript.exe //nologo //T:60 .\scripts\check_version.vbs
```

This command doesn't work:

```
check_login=C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\wscript.exe /scripts/check_login.vbs
```

Thank you 
Best regards 
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. cscript.exe must be used instaed of wscript.exe

This is the command:

```
check_login= C:\Windows\syswow64\cscript.exe //nologo //T:60 "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_login.vbs"
```

This is a nice howto test external scripts: [NSClient Testmode](https://docs.nsclient.org/howto/checks/)

Best regards
Steve